# How to identify login devices uniquely like Facebook?

Tags: uniqueidentifier

I have an application on Web and Mobile platform(iOS and Android), I am trying to identify from what devices user is login from, and keep a list of them for security purposes. Is there a universal ID for any devices like IMEI(mobile phones) for computers which uniquely identify each of them? I know that MACID is unique but a device could have multiple MACID if they online via various methods(Wifi, Ethernet Port or USB 3G dongle).

Answer (score 3):

Facebook uses cookies to determine whether a device is known to Facebook or not. You can use a long cookie (e.g. one that expires in 10 years) and set a GUID as it's value. You will then store this GUID in your database and associate it with the user.

As you will find out by now this only uniquely identifies a browser, not a device. If you control the application you should be able to get a device ID from Android and iOS platforms, or generate a GUID yourself. When the user logs in from an unknown browser, you can simply link all their devices based on their UserID.